# how to insert multiple records in one query?

Tags: elasticsearch

for example :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/users/2' -d '{ "firstname"   : "test" }'
```

insert only one record.

How to insert multiple records in one query?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use elasticsearch [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/docs-bulk.html). It allows you to insert multiple items with one request. Requests are POSTed to special endpoint `/_bulk` and look like this:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "field1" : "value2" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
```

Comment: @konstantin-v-salkhov What if I want to insert documents for the same index and of the same type, and want to use auto generated id's, is there a possibility to type: `{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1" } } ` only once, and then just the documents themselves? I guess not, as I could not find it in the documentation, but that would be a nice feature.

Comment: autogenerated ids are indeed working with "index" action

Comment: i inserted using postman, but the last document is not getting inserted

Comment: Make sure you have a new line after the last document. [Elastic Bulk docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough karma to comment in response to @Tadzys, but yes, bulk inserting documents to one or more indices without an id seems doable.  See "Inserting documents belonging to different types and indices in the same request" in [Elasticsearch: Bulk Inserting Examples](http://queirozf.com/entries/elasticsearch-bulk-inserting-examples).

From the referenced page:

```
POST http://path.to.your.cluster/_bulk
{ "index":{ "_index": "myIndex", "_type": "person" } }
{ "name":"john doe","age":25 }
{ "index":{ "_index": "myOtherIndex", "_type": "dog" } }
{ "name":"fido","breed":"chihuahua" }
```

*"Examples work for Elasticsearch versions 1.x, 2.x and probably later ones too."*

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never. This is how i made a curl request to the elastic server to dump multiple records using the Bulk API

```
curl -XPOST 'http://<my_host_name>:9201/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "1"} }{"id" : "AAA" , "name" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"}{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "2"} }{"id" : "BBB" , "name" : "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"}{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "3"} }{"id" : "CCC" , "name" : "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"}{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "4"} }{"id" : "DDD" , "name" : "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"}{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "5"} }{"id" : "EEE" , "name" : "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"}'
```

P.S: Elastic 5.x(atleast) doesn't seem to allow bulk create without an id attribute. Had to painfully come up with one for 100's of such records

Comment: Is there any way to generate the data in such a format from another elastic index?

Comment: [Hari K Murthy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960499/hari-k-murthy) any reason not to use **"index"** action instead of **"create"** if you want autogenerated ids? from what I understand the only difference between those 2 endpoints is that **"create"** requires the id and will fail in the case of duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

All answers above are right. I have a more specific one for you.

the port is **9200**, not 9201 as @Hari K Murthy's answer. Or maybe there're some other configurations.

The post url address is: `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk?pretty`. You may want to change to your own ip address.

Posted json is:

```
{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "1"} }
{"id" : "AAA" , "name" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"}
{ "create" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_document_type", "_id" : "2"} }
{"id" : "BBB" , "name" : "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"}
```

eg:
[image: use bulk api in postman]

NOTE: you have to format your json like one line metadata, another line data as the [bulk api doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) says.